# java desktop application with installer

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am novice in java desktop application development  i want to develop a desktop application with following requirement  installer for windows , mac os and linux  connect it to the application server(jboss7/websphere8)  and database server on remote as well as local data storage  i want to use javaFX for gui

Answer (score 1):

I think [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) is your answer.